# Any way around Facebook SDK limiting an app to posting only one photo at a time?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I am the creator of an app which in a previous version could post a map of the user's activity, and any photos they had taken. All the photos were uploaded into a photo album with the app name on Facebook.  I am now upgrading the app to a newer version but it seems that the new SDK restricts the user's ability to post more than one photo. I am told that it is only possible for an app to post one photo at a time. So the map can be posted but no photos. Or one photo and no map.   Is this the case, or is there a workaround?

If this is the case, any ideas as to why Facebook has limited the user's experience in this way?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not possible. But what’s stopping you from uploading the photos one by one, and then the map at the end? (If you don’t want a news feed post to be created for every single photo that gets uploaded, use the `no_story` parameter.)

Comment: Thanks for your input!  Appreciate it.